# Is it possible to print matrix into graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have

```
figure(9)
clf
plot(a,b,'.k')
```

and matrix A. How to dislay A in plot? Something with LaTeX interpreter? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do it this way.

```matlab
latex_word=['$' latex(sym(A)) '$']

text(x,y,latex_word,'Interpreter','latex') % x,y is where you put the latex into graph
```